# Does COUNT(1) - COUNT(column_name) only return the count of null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Does

```
COUNT(1) - COUNT(column_name) as total_nulls
```

only return the count of null values from a given column?

I feel confident it does but would like to know for certain.  Thanks

Comment: dont you mean `non-null` values?

Comment: Nope. Just want the nulls.  Trying to get the meta data from columns. i.e MAX, MIN,AVG,COUNT,DISTINCT, NULL etc...Just the numeric value of every column

Comment: If you want the nulls, you should try `COUNT(*) - COUNT(column_name)`, but now your question is kind of confuse about what you really want.

Comment: My mistake I just realize that was the real question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. A more logical and easy to read version would be:

```
select count(*) from myTable where myColumn is null;
```

PS: This version would also benefit from existing index.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an definitive answer!  Im querying for multiple columns (up to 40 in each table) and didnt want to have to write out WHERE x IS NULL AND Y IS NULL AND Z IS NULL etc...

Answer (score 4):

Why you dont try it?

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JQZOS89329)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Country] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Country])
VALUES
    ('Germany'),
    ('France'),
    (NULL),
    (NULL),
    ('Spain')
;

SELECT count(*), count(country), count(1)
FROM Table1
```

[image]

Comment: i know i definitely should of before posting a question...Was just looking for a quick answer and couldnt find it on google. Thanks for the demo!

Comment: Plus1 for the complete demo

Answer (score 1):

```
count(1)=count(*)--returns nulls
count(columnname)--won't return nulls
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is to use SUM.

```
select sum(case when MyColumn is null then 1 else 0 end)
```